# Microsoft AndroidNKD64 folder taking up huge disk space. How to remove?

Tags: visual-studio, android-ndk

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 community version. I noticed a huge folder (2.2Gbytes) containing AndroidNDK64 has been created.
Folder location is here;

```
C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b
```

I have uninstalled Xamarin from Visual Studio 2017 community. This folder remains here. Can I manually delete the folder without side effect later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question. I renamed the folder to another name. Launch Visual Studio. Experiment with it and discovered no side effect. I have deleted the folder. So far, so good.

Please note that I have uninstalled Xamarin from Visual Studio before deleting the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with

- C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c
- C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b
- C:\Microsoft\AndroidSDK

These are Visual Studio Installer packages dependencies (when you install android development related packages).

Only way to get rid of those cleanly, is to uninstall the Android related packages you don't need, from the VS Installer. Otherwise they will get automatically restored sooner or later when you update a VS instance, or even just a VS extension.